# Mongodb: Association not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In my app I there are 2 collections users and books. I am trying to add user  id whenever a book is added for some reason it is not working.

Here is my book schema. I want to add ownerId as user id.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: String,
    default: 'n/a',
  },
  ownerId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
    required: true,
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);

module.exports = Book;
```

User database entry

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b5666dba3bf3359b245e0ad"
    },
    "role": 0,
    "email": "monty69@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2b$10$KjTHzKSQCznCGQxYVprl3.3B3HV/aq0wGDqzQw.01P9lEXUn91Afe",
    "name": "jatta",
    "lastname": "sandhu",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Mongo version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3

Book Query

```js
addBook: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const book = await new Book(req.body).save();
      return res.status(200).json(book);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  }
```

But for somehow its not adding the user id in the book's entry. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the query for creating books.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet updated the post

Comment: ***for some reason it is not working*** what's that ? Are you getting any error? What does req.body contain?

Comment: So the problem is in my books collection I am not getting user id. Actually its throwing an error for ownerId being required and I am using passport for authentication

Comment: Because you validate your mongoose schema with **required: true** So put the `ownerId` inside the req.body object... what is the issue here?

Comment: Is it suppose to add ownerId automatically as when a user adds a book its gonna add the current logged in user or do I have to specify that?

Comment: Try this `req.body.ownerId = req.user.id`  if your request contains user information for logged in user

Comment: Thank You it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your `ownerId` with the logged in user `id`

```
addBook: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      req.body.ownerId = req.user.id
      const book = await new Book(req.body).save();
      return res.status(200).json(book);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  }
```